# How to control MediaPlayer volume and SoundPool volume separately?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media-player, soundpool, android-seekbar

i am developing a game and i am using `MediaPlayer` for the music and `soundpool` for the sound effects

I created a configuration menu with a `seekbar` for controlling music (`mediaplayer`) volume and another different `seekbar` for controlling sound effects (`soundpool`) volume

How can this be achieved without interfering between both volumes?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to set global volume values for MediaPlayer and SoundPool, how about you set the volume for each sound separately?

SoundPool supports volume settings on [`play()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#play(int, float, float, int, int, float)) and also during playback with [`setVolume()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#setVolume(int, float, float))

MediaPlayer, on the other hand has a separate [`setVolume()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setVolume(float, float)) for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have two variables, for music and effects; respectively.

Simply pass `musicVolume` to `pool.play()` when you play music, and pass `effectVolume` when you play a sound effect.

```
pool.play(musicId, musicVolume, musicVolume, 1, 0, 1);

pool.play(effectId, effectVolume, effectVolume, 1, 0, 1);
```